# Regexp to search and replace HTML in Geany

Tags: html, regex, search, replace, geany

I have a long list of countries like this:

```
<option value="Afghanistan" >Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Afrique du Sud" >Afrique du Sud</option>
<option value="Albanie" >Albanie</option>
```

And I'd like to cut out all the HTML code, so that I'm left with:

```
Afghanistan
Afrique du sud
Albanie
```

I'm using Geany, which allows me to use regular expression in my search and replace terms. What can expressions I use for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the lines are formatted just as in your example, you can search separately for `<option [^>]*>` and `</option>` and replace them with an empty string. Just be careful to select only your country list when doing the find-and-replace or the regex may go wild and replace unintended strings.